# Infinitive problem

Tags: infinitives

1)He gave me a pen to write with.

2)He gave me money to spend.

Why spend is not taking preposition as it is done in first example. Kindly help me.

Comment: Probably because you *spend money*. No preposition is needed there, so none is needed in the infinitive.

Answer (score 2):

'To ***spend***' is a transitive verb here and it needs no preposition (to spend time, money. etc.).

'To ***write***' needs the preposition '***with***' to show the instrument (to write with pen, pencil, chalk, etc.) used.

Comment: "She **spent** all his money **on** clothes"? "We **spent** everyday **on** the beach"

Comment: 'On' can be used, but there is not 'on' in the sentence of the question.

Comment: Your answer seems to suggest that because  ‘spend’ is a transitive verb it doesn't require a preposition. You should clarify (it's easy for a learner to gloss over the "here").

Comment: So what type of infinitive need preposition in the end.

Comment: In your case there two Simple Active Infinitives.